# Low Nice Date days are off on range

Tags: low, low-nice-date

I am using Low Nice Date (Good and simple addon BTW) to calculate elapsed time between current date and an even in years past. The problem seems to be that it is not taking into account the leap years.

Does anyone know if this can be corrected?   @Low ?

**EDIT

`{exp:low_nice_date:range from="{my_date}" to="{current_time}" localize="yes"}{years} YEARS - {months} MONTHS - {days} DAYS{/exp:low_nice_date:range}`

Where `{my_date}` is an epoch date set in a global variable as '875966400'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Low Nice Date calculates the range is just by some intervals between the two timestamps:

```
$data['years']  = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$data['months'] = floor(($diff - $data['years'] * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$data['days']   = floor(($diff - $data['years'] * 365*60*60*24 - $data['months']*30*60*60*24) / (60*60*24));
```

So yeah, it doesn't take leap years into account. I'm afraid that's the way it is.